# Recebendo nulo na variável para função count () PHP

Tags: php, post

Não estou conseguindo realizar o UPDATE no banco pois a página está me retornando que *$id_regiao2* está nulo na função *count()*.

Script:

```
            html += '                   <input type="hidden" name="id_regiao2[]" value=" ">';
            html += '                   <input type="hidden" name="nome_regiao[]" value="'+nome_regiao+'">';
            html += '                   <input type="hidden" name="nome_regiao2[]" value="'+nome_regiao+'">';
            html += '                   <input type="hidden" name="code_regiao[]" value="'+cdRegiao+'">';
            html += '                   <input type="hidden" name="code_regiao2[]" value="'+cdRegiao+'">';
```

Corpo HTML da página:

```
                <input type="hidden" name="id_regiao" value="<?=$regiao['idRegiao']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="nome_regiao[]" value="<?=$regiao['nome']?>">                 
                <input type="hidden" name="code_regiao[]" value="<?=$indice?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="id_regiao3[]" value="<?=$regiao['idRegiao']?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="nome_regiao3[]" value="<?=$regiao['nome']?>">                    
                <input type="hidden" name="code_regiao3[]" value="<?=$indice?>">[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]
```

Código da ação de atualizar o formulário:

```
            $id_regiao2   = $_POST['id_regiao2'];
    $id_regiao3   = $_POST['id_regiao3'];       

    $regioes_nm2  = $_POST['nome_regiao2'];
    $regioes_nm3  = $_POST['nome_regiao3'];

    $regioes_cd2  = $_POST['code_regiao2'];
    $regioes_cd3  = $_POST['code_regiao3'];

    $id_tecnico   = $_POST['id_tec'];
    $id_tecnico_reg = $_POST['id_tec_reg'];

    var_dump($id_regiao2);
    if (count($id_regiao2) == 0 || $id_regiao2 == null){
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($regioes_nm3); $i++) {

            $cd      = $regioes_cd3[$i];            
            $id_reg  = $id_regiao3[$i];


            // Atualiza o Gerente
            $id_ger       = Entrada::Int("id".$cd."_ger");
            $nome_ger     = Entrada::String("nome".$cd."_ger");
            $telefone_ger = Entrada::String("telefone".$cd."_ger");
            $email_ger    = Entrada::String("email".$cd."_ger");
            $senha_ger    = Entrada::String("senha1".$cd."_ger");

            $conexao->consulta("UPDATE proprietario_gerente SET "
                                ." idProprietario = $id,"
                                ." idRegiao = $id_reg,"
                                ." nome = '$nome_ger',"
                                ." telefone = '$telefone_ger',"
                                ." email = '$email_ger',"
                                ." senha = '".base64_encode($senha_ger)."',"
                                ." data_cadastro = CURDATE()"
                                ." WHERE idProprietario = $id AND idGerente = $id_ger"); 

            // Atualiza o Técnico
            foreach($id_tecnico_reg as $key => $id_tec_reg){
            if ( $id_tec_reg[$field] == $id_reg ){return $key;}
            foreach($id_tecnico as $id_tec => $id_tec_bd){
                if ($id_tec_bd[$field] == $key){return $id_tec;}
                    for ($j = 0; $j < $key; $j++){
                        $nome_tec       = $_POST["nome_tec".$j];
                        $telefone_tec   = $_POST["telefone_tec".$j];
                        $email_tec      = $_POST["email_tec".$j];
                        $senha_tec      = $_POST["senha1_tec".$j];
                        $conexao->consulta("UPDATE proprietario_tecnico SET "
                                            ." idProprietario = $id,"   
                                            ." idRegiao       = $id_reg,"
                                            ." nome           = '$nome_tec[$j]',"
                                            ." telefone       = '$telefone_tec[$j]',"
                                            ." email          = '$email_tec[$j]',"
                                            ." senha          = '".base64_encode($senha_tec[$j])."',"
                                            ." data_cadastro  = CURDATE()"
                                            ." WHERE idProprietario = $id AND idTecnico = $id_tec"); 
                                            $teste = $nome_tec[$j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }else{  
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($regioes_nm2); $i++) {
            $cd = $regioes_cd2[$i];

            // Grava Região
            $nome_reg = $regioes_nm2[$i];       
            $idRegiao = $conexao->consulta("INSERT INTO proprietario_regiao (idProprietario, nome, data_cadastro) VALUES ('$id', '$nome_reg', CURDATE())");

            // Grava Gerente
            $nome_ger = $_POST["nome".$cd."_ger"];
            $telefone_ger = $_POST["telefone".$cd."_ger"];
            $email_ger = $_POST["email".$cd."_ger"];
            $senha_ger = $_POST["senha1".$cd."_ger"];
            $ID_Inserido = $conexao->consulta("INSERT INTO proprietario_gerente (idProprietario, idRegiao, nome, telefone, email, senha, data_cadastro) VALUES ('$id', '$idRegiao', '$nome_ger', '$telefone_ger', '$email_ger', '".base64_encode($senha_ger)."', CURDATE())");

            // Grava Técnico
            $nome_tec = $_POST["nome".$cd."_tec"];
            $telefone_tec = $_POST["telefone".$cd."_tec"];
            $email_tec = $_POST["email".$cd."_tec"];
            $senha_tec = $_POST["senha1".$cd."_tec"];
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($nome_tec); $j++) {
                $ID_Inserido = $conexao->consulta("INSERT INTO proprietario_tecnico (idProprietario, idRegiao, nome, telefone, email, senha, data_cadastro) VALUES ('$id', '$idRegiao', '$nome_tec[$j]', '$telefone_tec[$j]', '$email_tec[$j]', '".base64_encode($senha_tec[$j])."', CURDATE())");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Esta conta infelizmente não pode permanecer ativa por ter sido criada para contornar um bloqueio automático de sistema. Use a conta original assim que as restrições passarem. Queira aproveitar a limiação para dar uma lida em  [Tour], [Ask], [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/70) e [Help]. Se tem dúvida em algum detalhe específico, reduzir o código a um [MCVE] pode ajudar bastante - Lembrando ainda que a pergunta original pode ser restaurada e editada.